# Get JsonResponse of a called function

Tags: php, json, symfony, jsonresponse

I'm working on a Symfony website. Basically I got two functions that returns both JsonResponse :

```
public function myFirstFunction() {
    mySecondFunction();
    return new JsonResponse(JsonResponse of mySecondFunction() ????);
}

public function mySecondFunction() {
    return new JsonResponse(array("result" => "ok", "sent" => "yes));
}
```

My question is : how can myFirstFunction() return the JsonResponse returned by mySecondFunction() ?

Comment: just return the second function. `return mySecondFunction();`

Comment: @Junaid That will not work in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply `return` it with `$this->` since you are calling a `method` within the current `object`. Returning the method *procedural style* `return mySecondFunction();` will not work.

```
public function myFirstFunction() {
    return $this->mySecondFunction();
    // return new JsonResponse(JsonResponse of mySecondFunction() ????);
}

public function mySecondFunction() {
    return new JsonResponse( array("result" => "ok", "sent" => "yes") );
}
```